# mypy can't find module in tox

Tags: python, virtualenv, mypy, tox

I'm trying to check `mypy` in `tox`, but it fails on missing modules, although these are installed in the tox's `virtualenv`.

Is there any standard procedure which can force `mypy` to search modules in standard location in virtualenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the package as [supporting typing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#how-imports-are-found).